# How do I Zipp several lists with different size using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i've got the following code

```
col1 = [ "Manjeet"] 
col2= [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]] 
col3= [ ["hello"], ["hello"], ["hello"] ]
```

and im trying to achieve this

```
result = [[ "Manjeet", ["a"], ["hello"]],
          [ "Manjeet", ["b"], ["hello"]],
          [ "Manjeet", ["c"], ["hello"]]]
```

With pandas, i've tried For cicle but it takes to long, Any suggestion?

Comment: What would you want if `col2` were only [["a"], ["b"]]? Do you want a tile?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
pd.DataFrame([col1,col2,col3]).T.ffill() #.values (for converting to array)
```

---

```
         0    1        2
0  Manjeet  [a]  [hello]
1  Manjeet  [b]  [hello]
2  Manjeet  [c]  [hello]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `zip_longest` + `ffill`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(col1, col2, col3)).ffill()

#         0    1         2
#0  Manjeet  [a]   [hello]
#1  Manjeet  [b]   [hello]
#2  Manjeet  [c]   [hello]
```

Should be faster for longer lists.

---

For a tiled filling you can take a similar approach, just expand the lists, then clean up the overhang in the end.

```
import numpy as np

col2 = [['a'], ['b']] # Only 2 elements, so third should be filled with 'a'

cols = [col1, col2, col3]
m = np.array([len(x) for x in cols])
m = np.ceil(m.max()/m).astype(int)

pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*[x*y for x,y in zip(cols, m)])).dropna()

#         0    1        2
#0  Manjeet  [a]  [hello]
#1  Manjeet  [b]  [hello]
#2  Manjeet  [a]  [hello]
```

Comment: it's splitting every single char into onw row

Comment: @tentativa123 not with the data you provided. Are you sure you have list as you indicated, or do you really have strings: `col1 = 'Manjeet'`

Comment: @tentativa123 strings are iterable, so the easiest fix would be to put the single string in a list that way you iterate over each string, not each character in the string.